# I stopped suddenly vs I suddenly stopped

Tags: grammar, word-usage, syntactic-analysis

Are these sentences both correct and what is the difference between them if both are grammatical ?

I stopped suddenly. 
I suddenly stopped.

Answer (score 3):

Both are grammatical but each requires context to fully explain how they could be different. The first might imply that you were in motion but stopped. The second might imply that you stopped doing something (other than moving).

In any case, standing alone without any other context they're too similar to say how they're different. (-:

Comment: I agree with this answer. In addition, I think that putting *suddenly* at the end puts special emphasis on the way you stopped.